# Ubuntu: package description

Tags: package-info

i am trying to obtain detailed information of available updates only, so i can read them from pipelines for further processing. I’ve already tried apt-cache show command but it displays two parts: the first represents the one i want and the second represents information about the installed update. I only need to get the first part which is the information about the available update. Can anybody provide hints on how to do that? I’ve browsed the web but no solution yet. Thanks